# Understanding conditional independence of two random variables given a third one

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading the Wikipedia article on [conditional independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence). There seems to be Two definitions for conditional independence of Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ given another one $Z$:

1. Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are
   conditionally independent given a
   third random variable $Z$ if and
   only if they are independent in
   their conditional probability
   distribution given $Z$. That is, $X$
   and $Y$ are conditionally
   independent given $Z$ if and only
   if, given any value of $Z$, the
   probability distribution of $X$ is
   the same for all values of $Y$ and
   the probability distribution of $Y$
   is the same for all values of $X$.
2. Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are
   conditionally independent given a
   random variable $Z$ if they are
   independent given $\sigma(Z)$: the
   $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Z$.

   Two events $R$ and $B$ are
   conditionally independent given a
   $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ if
       $$\Pr(R \cap B \mid \Sigma) = \Pr(R \mid \Sigma)\Pr(B \mid
       \Sigma)\ a.s.$$ where $\Pr(A \mid
       \Sigma)$ denotes the conditional
   expectation of the indicator
   function of the event $A$, given the
   sigma algebra $\Sigma$. That is,
   $$ \Pr(A \mid \Sigma) :=
       \operatorname{E}[\chi_A\mid\Sigma].$$

   Two random variables X and Y are
   conditionally independent given a
   $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ if the
   above equation holds for all $R$ in
   $\sigma(X)$ and $B$ in $\sigma(Y)$.

I can understand the second definition, but my questions are:

1. What does the first definitions mean
   actually? I have tried several times
   on reading it, but fail to get what
   it means? Can someone rephrase it
   using rigorous and clean language,
   for example, by writing the definition in terms of some formulae?
2. Do the two definitions agree with
   each other? Why?
3. **ADDED:** I was wondering if the following is the correct way to understand the first definition. Notice that $P(\chi_A \mid Z)$ is defined as $E(\chi_A \mid Z)$ and therefore is a random variable. When the conditional probability $P(\cdot \mid Z)$ is  "regular", i.e. when $P(\cdot \mid Z)(\omega)$ is a probability measure for each point $\omega$ in the underlying sample space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, does conditional independence between $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$ mean that $X$ and $Y$ are independent w.r.t. every probability measure defined by $P(\cdot \mid Z)(\omega), \forall \omega \in \Omega$? If yes, is the conditional probability $P(\cdot \mid Z)$ always  guaranteed to be "regular"? So that there is no need to explicitly write this "regular" assumption?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I just added my understanding of the first definition to my post as Part 3 of my questions. Hope someone can tell if it is correct.

Answer (score 5):

The first definition is the informal one, but at the same time seems rather convoluted to me.

I'd prefer: X and Y are conditionally independent with respect to a given Z iff

$P(X \; Y | Z) = P(X | Z ) P(Y | Z)$

Recall that conditioning one (or several) variables on the value of another, is (informally) the same as restricting the whole universe to a part of it.
Then, if you are given the value of $Z$, you can think as if you are defining new variables that are the same as the unconditioned but that are restricted to our new (smaller universe) $X' \equiv X | Z$ $Y' \equiv Y | Z$
The above formula simply states that $X'$ and $Y'$ are independent.

The first definition says the same, but applying (in words) the property that two variables are independent iff their conditioned probabilities are the same as the unconditioned : $A$ indep $B$ iff $P(A | B ) = P (A)$

Comment: You should really replace your first equation by something like: "For every measurable sets $A$ and $B$, $P(X\in A,Y\in B|Z)=P(X\in A|Z)P(Y\in B|Z)$ almost surely". And get rid of these horrible $X'\equiv X|Z$ and $Y'\equiv Y|Z$. And finally, why not define conditional independence cleanly and fully rigorously through test functions...

Comment: @Didier: I added my understanding of the first definition to my post as Part 3 of my questions. Would you be able to see if it is correct?

Comment: @Tim See the last sentence of my comment on the answer by @leonbloy.